# how to delete an element from json file using xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a .json file in MarkLogic as :

```
{
  "contextProductIdCDM": {
    "variables": {
      "source": "'Inm'", 
      "source_table_id": "'123'", 
      "Referdate": "normalize-space(string-join((J_MCCC, if(J_MCDC eq '') then '000' else J_MCDC),''))"
    }, 
    "$ref": "#/contexts/Closure"
  }, 
  "predcondition": "xyz=1"
}
```

I want to delete the predcondition and also want to delete some part of referdata also using xquery. Can anyone help how to achieve that?

Comment: It looks like your JSON is incomplete or invalid.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided an example of the desired changes, to know what you mean when you say that you want to delete some part of referdata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to remove the `precondition` field and modify the `contextProductIdCDM.variables.Referdate` value, you could address those JSON properties with XPath and use [`xdmp:node-delete()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-delete) and [`xdmp:node-replace()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-replace) functions:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $doc := fn:doc("/test.json")
return (
  xdmp:node-replace($doc/contextProductIdCDM/variables/Referdate, text{ "000" }), 
  xdmp:node-delete($doc/predcondition)
)
```

How it could be done in JavaScript; convert to a plain old object, make the modifications, then replace the document with that updated JSON object:

```
declareUpdate();
const doc = cts.doc("/test.json");
let obj = doc.toObject(); // create mutable representation
obj.contextProductIdCDM.variables.Referdate = '000'; //change the Referdate property value
delete obj.predcondition; // delete precondition field
xdmp.nodeReplace(doc, obj); // update the JSON document with the changes
```